# 入門書のコードをコピーして実行すると SyntaxError: invalid syntax エラーが出る

Tags: python

python初心者です。pythonの入門書のコードをコピーしながら学習してるのですが、エラーが出てしまい進めません。どうすればエラーを解消できるのか教えていただけると幸いです。

下の画像がエラーを起こしている時の画像になります。
2回ほどコードを写し直したのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
バージョンなども関係しているのでしょうか？
ちなみに入門書で用いられているバージョンは3.7です。また入門書の名前は『python入門』です。

[image]

Comment: 使用されている入門書をネットでざっと調べてみましたが「python入門　本」というキーワードではどの本か特定するることができませんでした。出版社、著者名などを追記していただければ、記述内容を比較して見てくれる方も現れるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

プログラムの中で if を使って処理を分岐させるあたりの書き方が間違っています。これは Python 2 でも Python 3 でも間違いです。

今はこうなっています。

```
print('その値は' + ('正' + if n > 0 else '0' if n == 0 else '負') + 'です。')
```

正しくは、たとえばこうです。プラス記号が無くなっています。

```
print('その値は' + ('正' if n > 0 else '0' if n == 0 else '負') + 'です。')
```

書かれていた内容の時点で元から間違っていたのか、コピーのどこかで間違えたのかは分かりませんが、どちらにせよ 1 行の中に if を入れるのであればこんな感じです。

SyntaxError、つまり「構文のエラー」とは、このようにプログラムの書き方を間違えているときに出るエラーです。このエラーが出たときは、指摘されているエラー発生個所の周辺を注意深く読んでみてください。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
何度も確認したつもりでしたが、‘正’の後にプラスが入っていることに気が付きませんでした。
コピーした本ではプラスは入っておらず、完全にケアレスミスをしていました。
わかりやすい解説ありがとうございました。
エラーも解消することができました。